# Url Rewrite Drop File Extension But Keep Querystring For Specific Page

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to match

https://www.example.com/abc/xyz.aspx?p1=a&p2=b&p3=c&p4=d

and I want to rewrite it to

https://www.example.com/abc/xyz?p1=a&p2=b&p3=c&p4=d

I've got this rewrite rule, but it's not working...

```
<rule name="Redirect Home Detail Pages">
  <match url="(\/abc\/xyz.aspx).*" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="/abc/xyz" appendQueryString="True" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like that:

```
<rule name="Redirect Home Detail Pages">
   <match url="^abc/xyz.aspx$" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/abc/xyz" appendQueryString="True" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```